# Jenkins Pipeline / Groovy Script with undefined variables

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to convert my large multi-config Jenkins job over to pipeline syntax so I can, among other things, split it across multiple nodes and combine my multiple stages into one job. Here's the part where I'm seeing trouble:

```
def build_test_configs = [:]
def compilers = ['gnu', 'icc']
def configs = ['debug', 'default', 'opt']

for (int i = 0; i < configs.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < compilers.size(); j++) {
        def node_name = ""
        if ("${compilers[j]}" == "gnu") {
            node_name = "node001"
        } else {
            node_name = "node002"
        }
        build_test_configs["${node_name} ${configs[i]}"] = {
            node ("${node_name}") {
                stage("Build Test ${node_name} ${compilers[j]} ${configs[i]}") {
                    unstash "${node_name}-tarball"
                    sh "$HOME/software/jenkins_scripts/nightly.sh ${configs[i]} ${compilers[j]} yes $WORKSPACE"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

parallel build_test_configs
```

My problem is that `${compilers[j]` and `$configs[i]` are undefined when I get to the part where I'm trying to build up a dictionary of `build_test_configs` on line 13. It would appear that the check on line 8 is working just fine.

#### Update

I don't have an error message per se. The script doesn't produce any runtime errors. The unexpected output is that the names of the stages are:

- Build Test node001 null null
- Build Test node001 null null
- Build Test node002 null null

And the `nightly.sh` script is getting passed `null` parameters as well.

Comment: good question! maybe dump the error message here?

Comment: Doh! Sorry about leaving that out @KevinBurnett. I've updated the question to include the output.

Comment: Yep. I was simplifying my script and missed that one. It's been fixed. Thanks @HuguesMoreau.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the expected behavior: Jenkins Pipeline scripts are written in Groovy but what is actually executed is a transformation of that (the term they use is "continuation-passing style transformation"). For example, some parts will run on the master, some on the slave nodes.

This involves a lot of magic that flies way above my head, but at our level it means we have to work with constraints in the syntax & constructs we use.

See the ["fundamentals" paragraph of this article](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/01/pipeline-scalability-best-practice/):

> To understand Pipeline behavior you must understand a few points about how it executes.

1. Except for the steps themselves, all of the Pipeline logic, the
   Groovy conditionals, loops, etc execute on the master. Whether
   simple or complex! Even inside a node block!
2. Steps may use executors to do work where appropriate, but each step has a small on-master overhead too.
3. Pipeline code is written as Groovy but the execution
   model is radically transformed at compile-time to Continuation
   Passing Style (CPS).
4. This transformation provides valuable safety
   and durability guarantees for Pipelines, but it comes with
   trade-offs: Steps can invoke Java and execute fast and efficiently,
   but Groovy is much slower to run than normal. Groovy logic requires
   far more memory, because an object-based syntax/block tree is kept
   in memory.
5. Pipelines persist the program and its state frequently to
   be able to survive failure of the master.

Also see [JENKINS-41335](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41335) discussing support of variables across the script.

Edit: ah, yes, as pointed in the comments, the new declarative model allows to define an [environment](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Environment-variables) with variables that would be passed the way you need... Don't know how to do that in scripted pipeline without JENKINS-41335 but it seems further evolutions will now happen in declarative land :/

Comment: So part of my problem is that I'm using the "scripted pipeline" syntax instead of the new "declarative pipeline" syntax. It seems that things would be much easier if I could use the latter (especially in terms of finding documentation), but because I need to generate my list of stages procedurally and run them in parallel, the "declarative pipeline" syntax is not an option.

Comment: Hmm maybe I'm mixing things up a bit ? But in all cases I think you are still restricted about what you can use in a `stage` step.

Comment: Maybe I need to step back and rethink the whole process I'm going through. I'm having a hard time finding advice on converting a complex multi-config job to a pipeline.