# Is it possible to define a stage of a Jenkins declarative pipeline in a helper method or shared library?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on a team that has a lot of projects with independent Jenkins declarative pipeline files.  Most of those files duplicate a lot of the pipeline definition.  We would benefit from share collections of `step` and an entire `stage` in a shared library.  While the former appears to be possible with declarative pipelines the later does not.

The question of `stage` definitions was covered in June 2018 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50634592/can-i-use-a-closure-to-define-a-stage-in-a-jenkins-declarative-pipeline) with the accepted answer being NO.  A later [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55636671/1284852) recommended using script blocks to share stages ... coming up with a messy scripted/declarative pipeline. Moreover, the [request](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49135) on the Jenkins jira is still open and hasn't had any meaningful movement since April 2018.

So before I waste a bunch of time jamming a square peg in a round hole or ignoring a perfectly reasonable solution, **is the best solution to just embrace scripted pipelines?**  That syntax would allow me to define usable chucks of the pipeline at any level. I could have one-liner pipelines for cases where a "cookie cutter" build is acceptable, or larger customized pipelines that reuse a few complete stages but perhaps deploy code in a different manner.